# APK update deletes database file from filesystem

Tags: android, database, android-install-apk

**Our issue:**

We do have a cordova based android app in PlayStore, which is using sqlite plugin to store data in database. We already updated the version of this app from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 successfully in the past, with no issues.
Now we tried to update the app to a newer version 1.1.1, which holds just some minor bugfixes. But when we install the update over the version from PlayStore our DB gets deleted, and all data from previous version is lost.

After some researches with adb tool, we figured out that the DB file at 
"file:///data/user/0/my.app.id/databases/app.db" (my.app.id is only a dummy placeholder for this post) gets deleted while app update. This means the DB file is deleted already **before** the updated app even started for first time.

This behaviour only appears when updating exact this version 1.1.0 from PlayStore. All other version (e.g. from 1.0.0 direct to 1.1.1) do update properly without data/DB loss.

**Things we tried:**

- Restored the version 1.1.0 from our GIT repo and then update with 1.1.1 APK => no data loss, everything works as expected
- Created empty cordova app with no plugins and content. Installed this app as update over 1.1.0 from PlayStore => DB file gets deleted
- Created empty native android APK and installed as update over 1.1.0 => DB file gets deleted
- Downloaded APK 1.1.0 from PlayStore, opened it, increased version string and signed app again with corresponding keystore file => no data loss and version string is shown as 1.1.1
- Downloaded APK 1.1.0 from PlayStore, opened it and replaced content with 1.1.1 APK content, signed app and updated over previous 1.1.0 version => not data loss but app crashes after few seconds
- Dwonloaded APK 1.1.0 from PlayStore. Downloaded APK 1.0.0 from PlayConsoel. Opened APK file 1.0.0 and only increaded version string to 1.1.1. Signed the app and installed over 1.1.0 => DB file gets delted
- Uploaded version 1.1.1 to PlayStore as Beta, and installed over 1.1.0 => DB filte gets deleted
- Searched the web and stackoverflow for similar issues, but with no result matching our case

We are really consfused and dont know what is happening, as we have some similar apps in store with same logic/codebase and all updating properly. So any hint where to look would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you didn't change DB when you update 1st time from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 and now you are change something and update DB version so in this case you have to do migration.(just thinking). System should not touch DB if version of DB the same as in previous app version.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. We did not make any changes on DB that whould require migration or similar. Also when updating from 1.0.0 to 1.1.1 the DB file also stays intact. So I think it must be something specific to version 1.1.0 from PlayStore. As mentioned when restoring version 1.1.0 from git repo and then upgrading to 1.1.1 the DB also stays intact.

Comment: Just for clarify. You don't change DB version and it's keep deleting. You said about app version but nothing about DB version.

Comment: No I did not change any DB version. In fact I even dont know where i could change the DB version at all. The DB gets initialized with cordova sqlite plugin using following line of code "db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'app.db', iosDatabaseLocation: 'Documents' });". This line of code was not touched since initial version 1.0.0